# man sections mapping

Tags: linux, system-info

where I can to find mapping between man section number and it's description in standalone mashine.
In other words, where I can to find description of some man section when I have not connection to Internet?
For example:

```
1    -> User commands
2, 3 -> Linux programmer's manual
and so on...
```

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, there's a one-line description of each section number in `man 1 man`.

On most Unices (including Linux), `man N intro` describes what sort of things are in section `N`.

Comment: Wunderbar!!! man N intro is what I need!
(but there is nothing about that in man 1 man)